# Laravel 5.7 Notification ->line there is no option to escape html but it was working in 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

I have the same code notification in Laravel 5.5 and 5.7, for Laravel 5.5, I am able to use `<strong>` in ->line, but in 5.7 it will escape it.

In my notification blade view file, I set {{ ]} or {!! !!}, I still can't display html in my email. In 5.5, I do not need to escape it still work.

```
\\this is when I not escape
&lt;strong&gt;2019-01-13 15:41&lt;/strong&gt;



 \\this is when I escape
 <strong>2019-01-13 15:37</strong>
```

what I want is display bold like below.

**2019-01-13 15:37**

both method also displayed the tag, It will not bold the text. The same coding work in 5.5 but not Laravel version 5.7.20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @driesvints

> You don't need withoutDoubleEncoding in 5.7 so you can remove that.
>
> As you can see lines are being escaped in the template:
>
> framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php
>
> Line 15 in d818fd1
>
> {{ $line }}  So you'll need to indicate that the line has HTML in it.
>   Try this:
>
> ->line(new HtmlString('Due Date: **' . Carbon::parse($this->info->created_at)->format('Y-m-d
>   H:i').'**'));

This is solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From 5.5 to 5.6 upgrade, the Laravel blade double encoding is removed. If you would like to maintain the previous behaviour of preventing double encoding, you may use the `Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding` method like the following.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot()
   {
       Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding();
   }
}
```

You can read more about it on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0).

Comment: I added the `Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding();` , and `return (new MailMessage)->line('Due Date: <strong>123</strong>');` still cannot get the bold font. Can you test?